# Wrong collation with CREATE DATABASE AS COPY OF on Sql Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I want to copy an SQL Azure database to a new database on Azure using the **CREATE DATABASE  AS COPY OF**  but the collation of the new database is not the same as the source.

Looking at the documentation of the **ALTER DATABASE** of SQL Azure, we cannot change the collation of a database.

Is there a way to create a copy of an SQL Azure database on Azure and keeping the collation?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new SQL server on Azure and copied the database using the same technique and the collation is now the expected one. There was something wrong with my original server.